# Grails pagination tag inside Angular Asset pipeline is possible?

Tags: angularjs, grails

I created a grails 3 restful application with an angular 1 profile. I am trying to utilize pagination and it works insofar as data is returned per the max and offset variables. However, all that is useless if I can't get pagination directives to be rendered into list.html. Is it possible to utilize

I get error namespace g is not bound from intellij and it appears not to be doing anything at runtime. I don't see any paging ..... any sample would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant use GSP tags in HTML. You have to use an AngularJS alternative.